# Horizon reingest not working

Tags: horizon

I do run `horizon db reingest range 6500 7104` in order to pull some missing entries to my validator.

I run into this error:

```
INFO[2020-05-04T15:52:55.425Z] Ingestion system initial state                current_state="reingestHistoryRange(fromLedger=6500, toLedger=7104, force=false)" pid=21477 service=expingest
INFO[2020-05-04T15:52:55.432Z] Processing ledger                             commit=false graph=false ledger=true pid=21477 sequence=6500 service=expingest state=false
ERRO[2020-05-04T15:52:55.434Z] Error in ingestion state machine              current_state="reingestHistoryRange(fromLedger=6500, toLedger=7104, force=false)" error="error processing ledger sequence=6500: Error creating ledger reader: ledger not found" next_state=stop pid=21477 service=expingest
INFO[2020-05-04T15:52:55.434Z] Shut down                                     pid=21477 service=expingest
2020/05/04 15:52:55 error processing ledger sequence=6500: Error creating ledger reader: ledger not found
```

What I noted is that the HISTORY_ARCHIVE_URL (`https://history.stellar.org/prd/core-testnet/core_testnet_001`) is actually giving me a 404.

How can I fix that?

Comment: What version of Horizon are you running? The 404 is a red herring. The directory is not available for listing, but you can see data at e.g. http://history.stellar.org/prd/core-testnet/core_testnet_001/.well-known/stellar-history.json

Comment: It happened in 12.5 and 13.0.

Comment: Those are stellar-core versions, not Horizon versions

Comment: Sorry: `"horizon_version": "v1.2.0",   "core_version": "v12.5.0"`

Answer (score 2):

Stellar-core database must contain the ledgers in the range you want to ingest. You can make stellar-core to process them by running:

```
stellar-core catchup 7104/1000
```

This will process 1000 ledgers before 7104, including 7104.

Comment: Hm, that brings me to the next error: https://dpaste.org/n28o

Comment: Additionally: Is there a way to define the starting ledger on startup? If so, I'd just throw the container away.

Comment: This Stellar-Core error in strange, you can try to remove `buckets` directory it should help. Which docker image are you using?

Comment: That does not help. I'm using https://hub.docker.com/r/stellar/quickstart/ - I just launched a brand new instance (`"horizon_version": "v1.2.0", "core_version": "v13.0.0"`) and it has almost exactly the same error: https://dpaste.org/nry7

Comment: What is exact command you use to start a container?

Comment: On aws it's a bit more complicated, but I was just able to reproduce it locally on my macbook with just `docker run --rm -it -p "8000:8000" --name stellar stellar/quickstart --testnet` https://dpaste.org/h6y9

Comment: Please try running `stellar-core new-db` before catchup command. If this doesn't help I'll ask someone from Stellar-Core team for help.

Comment: That command yielded this: https://dpaste.org/dAH7; however the error still persists: https://dpaste.org/JTYk - thanks for your help!

Comment: Hm, okay, i tried again and it seems to be working now. Weird.

Just to clarify: I need to do this catchup until I have closed the gap between `history_elder_ledger` and `core_latest_ledger` and then run the horizon command?

And: Is it possible to give the start position upon booting the container? That would help tremendously.

Comment: Okay, this is unfortunately not solved. When I run this new-db stuff, then the entire validator stops working: It's no longer catching up and stops working.

Comment: And the reingest of horizon still throws the same error, even after catchup.

Comment: > When I run this new-db stuff, then the entire validator stops working
OK, I assumed that you don't run a validator when reingesting.

Comment: First of all, stellar/quickstart is a single purpose image - it just catchup to testnet and pubnet and start serving requests. It's really hard to do any admin tasks. I would recommend using https://github.com/stellar/go/tree/master/services/horizon/docker that's just a wrapper around horizon binary so should be easy to run all commands.

Comment: Second, you either need stop stellar-core instance before running new-db or have another instance where you can run catchup and point horizon to it. I think the former is easier. So the process should be the following.
1. Start stellar-core and horizon, wait for horizon to ingest a few couple ledgers. Check history_elder_ledger value.
2. Stop stellar-core and horizon.
3. Catchup stellar-core to any range pre history_elder_ledger you want.
4. Reingest that range using horizon.
5. Restart everything stellar-core (new-db and run) and horizon.

Comment: Above has one disadvantage. It's possible that a new gap will be formed while reingestion. I think this article can help: https://www.stellar.org/developers/software/known-issues.html

Comment: Hm, maybe I'm totally missing the point here. I have a container running on aws and i just want it to have a history up to a specific entry, e.g. so that I can query price history. I don't want to do admin tasks, I'm fine with throwing away and restart. That feels like a very common thing and maybe I'm just using the wrong setup.

The image you recommend is only horizon, right? Not stellar core?

Comment: Okay, I think i've found that i need to remove CATCHUP_RECENT from `/opt/stellar-default/testnet/core/etc/stellar-core.cfg` and `/opt/stellar-default/pubnet/core/etc/stellar-core.cfg` upon container start, let's see.

Comment: Okay, that did not have any effect at all.

Comment: Okay, i as well added `CATCHUP_COMPLETE=true` and made some progress. I'm now able to reingest to `50002` - and not one entry more or i'll get back the error from above. What am I doing wrong? `stellar-core` says it's syned; `stellar-core catchup` is still the same error.